# Error: Call to undefined method get() in PHPUnit Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, get, phpunit

I am trying to execute my first unit test with PHPUnit 9.0.0 and Symfony 5.1.8. This test must to pass if the HTTP response is 200.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Infrastructure\Api\Controller;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ControllerTests extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
     public function route(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    
    }

}
```

I obtain the error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. Tests\Infrastructure\Api\Controller\SupplierControllerTests::route
>    Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Infrastructure\Api\Controller\SupplierControllerTests::get()

I thought the Get method was a default method, imported by PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase, but it do not look that.

Have I to add a Get method into my class ControllerTests? How can i develop it to test the HTTP response?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend the WebTestCase provided by Symfony, not the default TestCase provided by PHPUnit.

Here is an example for a similar test you are trying to write:

```php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PostControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testShowPost()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/post/hello-world');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: So i have to use another command to throw the test? (Actually, i was used ./vendor/bin/phpunit)

Comment: I said because i obtain the error: "
Tests\Infrastructure\Api\Controller\ControllerTests::route
RuntimeException: Class "App\Kernel" doesn't exist or cannot be autoloaded. Check that the KERNEL_CLASS value in phpunit.xml matches the fully-qualified class name of your Kernel or override the "Tests\Infrastructure\Api\Controller\ControllerTests::createKernel()" method.". I am looking the reason but i do not find that.